# infowindow auto-display from a KML file

Tags: google-maps

First question on here so please be gentle with me.

I am making progress but am still on a steep learning curve using multiple layers within google maps API (not google earth).  I've managed some harder stuff but this simple task has beaten me so far.

So ......
what I want to do is have an infowindow or balloon displayed automatically when a new layer is associated with my map ... no clicks, it should just appear at the lat/lon point given.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I think for the `Multiple layers within google maps` you may use `Fusion Tables Layer API`, please refer [here](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/multiple_layers_per_map) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. I have managed to add multiple layers to my own maps and that is what gave the need to have an infowindow or balloon appear automatically from the KML layer file (so that the user can see instantly which layer has been added).